# Is it possible to add CPTLegend in UIview not a CPTGraphHostingView?

Tags: ios, core-plot, pie-chart

I am trying to add the CPTLegend in uiview how can i add.Basically many people adding in Graph hosting view. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

All visible parts of a Core Plot graph, including the legend (drawn by `CPTLegend`), are Core Animation layers that are derived from a common superclass, `CPTLayer`. These layers rely on the hosting view to set up the coordinate transform and event handling and to handle layout changes.

Why do you need to have a legend that is not attached to a graph? `CPTLegend` depends on plots both to determine the contents of the legend and to actually draw it. These plots are normally part of a graph, so you should have one available to use as a host for the legend.

Enlarge the hosting view to cover the whole area where the pie chart and legend should appear. Change the `centerAnchor` of the pie chart to move it away from the center of the hosting view and position the legend on the other side of the graph. The separator view can be placed on top of the hosting view to separate the plot from the legend. Note that Core Animation hosting views don't allow subviews, so it needs to be a sibling (i.e., have the same superview) of the hosting view, not a subview.

Comment: In my design left side PieChart is showing , in middle one line separator is showing and right side CPTLegend need to show.In this situation middle line is not plotting properly.

Comment: How are you drawing the separator line?

Comment: How? Is it a custom view?

Comment: self.lineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(graphView.frame.size.width / 1.8, graphView.frame.origin.y + 30, 2, totalHeight - 60)];